# Git merge with optional changes

Tags: git, merge

For example a have a branch I worked with for along time. And I don't longer need some code I've commited. Can I merge my branch in master and pick only those changes I need while merging, or I can only create a new commit with those changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do 2 different things:

1. Rebase the branch (removing the unused commits) and then merge the branch to master.
2. Cherry pick the commits you want to master.

[**1**] When you rebase your current branch, you'll see something like this:

> ```
> pick 253c0d6 [OOGA-255] remove @Ignore for fixed test on incremental build 
> pick 0a70bad [OOGA-3223] Add dwarves
> pick c8bff81 [OOGA-200] Cyberspace crashes while eating cake
> pick 5fb6666 Implemented new quark flavor 
> pick 412b9ff [HAHA-4062] Ted slipped and fell on his but..
> ```
>
> ...

Simply delete the lines (commits) that you don't want to keep. Once you've finished rebasing, you can merge your branch to master:

```
git checkout master
git merge old-branch
```

[**2**] In order to cherry pick:

a. Go to the branch you want to cherry pick *to* (master).
b. Get a list of the commits you want to cherry pick:

```
git log --stat=125,125 old-branch
```

c. Cherry pick!

```
git cherry-pick <SHA>
```

Answer (score 1):

read about interactive rebases, e.g. here: https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase

or, if the situation is simple, you might be able to cherry-pick the relevant commits on master.